# onClick() doesn't trigger function in React-Native App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In my react-native mobile app I have written a component called Row in row.js that contains a `TouchableOpacity`  with an `onClick()` event handler. However when the component is clicked the function doesn't run.

The Row component displays some text about a particular film and should run the handlePress() function when clicked:

```
const Row = props => (
  <TouchableOpacity onClick={() => props.handlePress(props.imdbID)} style={styles.row}>
    <Text>Some text</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
)
```

In a separate app.js file, the handlepress function has been written and is passed to the Row component as a prop. The imdbID variable is also passed to the component from the film object:

```
handlePress = imdbID => {
  // do something with imdbID
}
```

```
<Row handlePress={this.handlePress} {...film} />
```

Please can someone tell me what I am doing wrong and why the function doesn't run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you take a look at the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback#props), it doesnt have `onClick`.

You should use [`onPress`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback#onpress).

```
const Row = props => (
  //          using onPress
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => props.handlePress(props.imdbID)} style={styles.row}>
    <Text>Some text</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
)
```

Answer (score 2):

React-Native doesnt provide `onClick` functionality , it gives `onPress` instead , so replace onClick with `onPress`

```
const Row = props => (
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => props.handlePress(props.imdbID)} style={styles.row}>
    <Text>Some text</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
)
```

hope this helps ,feel free for doubts

Answer (score 0):

React native does not have `onClick` for `TouchableOpacity`.
Use `onPress` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use `onPress()` instead of of `onClick()`

improved code

```
const Row = props => (
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> props.handlePress(props.imdbID)} style={styles.row}>
    <Text>Some text</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use onPress instead of onClick and be sure you are importing touchable from react-native not gesture-handler